# How to set Microsoft Graph Onlinemeeting API Settings like AdditionalData i..e autoAdmittedUsers,restrictAnonymousUserJoining,etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created Online meeting using Microsoft Graph API  using [Auth Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
Below is the code:

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClientCredential();
            var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
            {
                StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-10-01T10:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
                EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-10-01T11:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
                Subject = "Create Online Meeting-Without user login to Office 365"
            };

            return await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
                 .Request()
                 .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);

**OR **
            return await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.CreateOrGet(externalId, null, 
                  dateTimeOffsetSTART, meetingParticipants, dateTimeOffsetEND, sSubject).Request().PostAsync();
```

My question is I am want to set some properties like:
1.Anonymous user cant join meeting by just putting joining web url in the browser.
2.AutoAdmittedUser setting.Tried below code,but not working and i am not clear about how to set the values

```
IDictionary<string,object> dAdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
          dAdditionalData.Add("autoAdmittedUsers", "everyone");
          onlineMeeting.AdditionalData = dAdditionalData;
```

3.Meeting attendee should be able to join meeting just by putting joining web url in the browser without
login.
4.Lobby waiting not for guest only for attendee.
5.Presenters setting
6.How to set externalid
7.How to generate attendance report of attendee attended meeting with entry exit time.

Comment: Where did you find `restrictAnonymousUserJoining` property?

Comment: i didnt find it just my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Anonymous user can't join meeting by just putting joining web url in the browser.

No such property.

> 2.AutoAdmittedUser setting.

`autoAdmittedUsers` is available in Beta version but it is **Read-only**. See [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). Please note that "**The autoAdmittedUsers property is obsolete. Use lobbyBypassSettings.scope instead for meeting option configurations.**" See details in the fourth question below.

> 3.Meeting attendee should be able to join meeting just by putting joining web url in the browser without login.

No such property.

> 4.Lobby waiting not for guest only for attendee.

No such property. There is only a [`lobbyBypassSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/lobbybypasssettings?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) property but it can't meet your requirement. `lobbyBypassSettings` can only be set with [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

> 5.Presenters setting

`allowedPresenters` property. Possible values are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta#onlinemeetingpresenters-values). Can only be set with [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

> 6.How to set externalid

See `externalId` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). It can only be set with [onlineMeeting: createOrGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

> 7.How to generate attendance report of attendee attended meeting with entry exit time.

No such endpoint that returns the report of attendee attended meeting with entry exit time information.

These properties are available in Beta version. Make sure you [install **Microsoft.Graph.Beta** package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk).

Example to set `lobbyBypassSettings` and `allowedPresenters`:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
    Subject = "User Token Meeting333",
    LobbyBypassSettings = new LobbyBypassSettings
    {
        Scope = LobbyBypassScope.Organizer,
        IsDialInBypassEnabled = false
    },
    AllowedPresenters = OnlineMeetingPresenters.Organizer
};

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Example to set `externalId`:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var startDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00");

var endDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00");

var subject = "User Token Meeting444";

var externalId = "12365478";

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
    .CreateOrGet(externalId,null,endDateTime,null,startDateTime,subject)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Please note that you can't update `externalId` after the meeting is created. And you can't set `lobbyBypassSettings` and `allowedPresenters` with [onlineMeeting: createOrGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). But you can update `lobbyBypassSettings` and `allowedPresenters` after a meeting has been created with `externalId`:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    LobbyBypassSettings = new LobbyBypassSettings
    {
        Scope = LobbyBypassScope.Organizer,
        IsDialInBypassEnabled = false
    },
    AllowedPresenters = OnlineMeetingPresenters.Organizer
};

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["{meeting id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Comment: thanx for detail ans.will try n let u know.

Comment: `No such endpoint that returns the report of attendee attended meeting with entry exit time information.` is  your remark.Now i need this report,is there any possibility to get report now or anything similar.Is this available in Beta version.its urgent req.

Comment: @anu No. As I answered in the last month, this feature is not provided in Microsoft Graph yet. Please see this user voice post to get more information: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33989875-view-or-export-a-list-of-users-who-attended-a-meet.